# Как скрыть неактивный элемент?

Tags: javascript, css

Имеется меню:

```
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item1"><a href="#">item1</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="subItem1">subitem1</li>
        <li class="subItem1">subitem2</li>
        <li class="subItem1">subitem3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>


    var ul = $('.menu>li>ul');
    var a = $('.menu>li>a');

    ul.hide();

    a.click(function() {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        a.removeClass('active');
        ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');
      }
    })
```

Изначально `.menu>.item1>ul` и `.menu>.item2>ul` при помощи цикла `for` получают `display: none;` при клике на `.menu>.item1>a`.
При помощи `this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle` `.menu>.item1>ul` получает `display: block/none`. Задача состоит в том, чтобы при нажатии допустим на `.menu>.item2>a` (которое раскрывается как положено) скрывался `.menu>.item1>ul`. В `JQuery` свободно применяется `filter(':visible').slideUp()`, но интересует только ванилла.

Comment: исправьте структуру - sub ul должен быть внутри li (данный момент ul>li+ul>li), а должно быть ul>li>ul>li

Comment: а что мешает в методе или ф-и, которые отвечают за toggle, в цикле ставить display:none всем нужным элементам кроме фильтронутого (нажатого по ссылке)

Comment: на jq юзал бы not(), а на ванилле как?)

Comment: @urpride посмотрите https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter или сбросьте jq код и vanilla если таковой имеется

Comment: jq добавил, а в ванилле в функции show только одна строка this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('none');